# BMS using BQ28Z620 (2s)

Tags: batteries, texas-instruments, bms

I am having a bit of trouble with understanding the provided implementation from the datasheet. I don't understand why the serial resistor connected to VC2/Pin11 is only 5R and has no 0.1uF decoupling cap compared with VC1/PIN12.

In the datasheet, it says, "Series input resistors between 100 Ω and 1 kΩ are recommended for effective cell balancing". 5R seems way too small? Did I miss anything？

Thank you so much in advance!
[image: Implementation on Datasheet]

[image: Cell Blancing]